# Unknown image classification category

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow

I followed Tensor flow for poets and classified images into 4 categories  c1,c2,c3,c4. Now I have lot of images whose category is not known but I know for sure that those images falls into only one of the four categories. And also I know some images will no fall in to c3 and c4 for sure. ANyway can I use those clues and images to retrain the data ? How ?